# How does Visual Studio know Project is a VB project or How can I convert my project to C# project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-to-c#

I am looking to convert my project from a VB project into a C# project.  How do Visual studio recocgnize that the project is a VB project?  I have been looking through my project file in Notepad and I notice some of my old VB classes (they have been converted to C# by a useless utility).  How can I change the actual Project and its files into C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(AFAIK) Visual Studio uses the file extension to know what sort of file it is `.vbproj` is a vb project file `.vb` is a vb source file, etc.

You can't just convert a project from one type to another, you will have to re-write each file individually but to get you most of the way there you can convert the code using an online converter:

http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/

http://converter.telerik.com/

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Instant troll note: Why convert it at all? VB is much better: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/10-reasons-why-visual-basic-is-better-than-c/

Comment: Are you sure it's by the extension?  That seems to be a bit risky to me.  I could have sworn it was in the project file somewhere, but I just looked at one of my projects and there was nothing in the file that indicated it was C#.  Unless it's the project GUID?

Comment: And then there's the build target - `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`

Comment: Thanks for that.  I actually started just recreating the projects and just converting the files.  Really annoying.  People say VB is better, I don't believe them.